# Make use of wrapping layouts in Craft

Tags: templating

I am a beginner when it comes to Craft and I have a hard time finding good detailed tutorials when it comes to specific questions. I know that Craft has it's own documentation but for me it's a little hard to find exactly what I want. So what I would like to know is how you can embed the header and the footer in every page with a simple tag.

I know that in Expression Engine all you had to do is was the following:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>News Site</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    {layout:contents}
  </body>
</html>
```

And on any other page you could add this tag and you were done.

```
{layout="site/.html-layout"}

{exp:channel:entries channel="news"}
  <h2>{title}</h2>
  {summary}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

How can I achieve the same thing in Craft? Thank you for your time and help :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Craft's uses the Twig templating language. The official Twig documentation http://twig.sensiolabs.org is really good, highly recommended to read most of it!

For your specific problem have a look at the section about the [`extends`](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/extends.html) tag. It explains how to define blocks and extend other template files. Another important technique is including partials into a template with the [`include`](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/include.html) tag.

For a good and rather simple example I would recommend to read the source code of Pixel and Tonic's [On The Rocks](https://github.com/pixelandtonic/ontherocks/blob/master/craft/templates/index.html) Craft demo page.